# (php скрипт) анализ позиций сайта в поисковой системе

Tags: seo, php

Доброго времени суток. Кто ранее сталкивался с подобным? Интересует есть ли система на php для анализа позиций сайта в поисковике по ключевым словам. Интересуют любые варианты, куски кода, статейки и т.д. Хочу для начала понять принцип работы.

Цель создать свой такой инструмент.

Answer (score 2):

[Яндекс.XML](http://help.yandex.ru/xml/) — сервис, позволяющий отправлять запросы к поисковой базе Яндекса и получать ответы в формате XML.